# Problemas con Composer a la hora de desinstalar un paquete

Tags: php, composer

En la aplicación que tengo se instala *Composer* (no lo hice yo) y con él varias librerías. Ahora se ha dejado de usar una de ellas y hay que desinstalarla.

Como se instaló con *Composer* creo que debería desinstalarse con el mismo, para evitar problemas (no quiero borrar la carpeta directamente).

La librería que se quiere desinstalar es *Reportico*.

Accedo al servidor, remotamente con ***Putty***.

Hasta ahora lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

1. Conectarme al servidor de manera remota como usuario root
2. Acceder a la carpeta donde se encuentra `composer.phar`
3. Ejecutar `composer.phar` con  `php composer.phar`

Hasta aquí lo sencillo, se me muestra la siguiente pantalla:

```
############ /var/www#php composer.phar
```

> `Do not run Composer as root/super user!` See https://getcomposer.org/root `for details`

```
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 1.4.1 2017-03-10 09:29:45

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help                     Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
  -V, --version                  Display this application version
      --ansi                     Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi                  Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction           Do not ask any interactive question
      --profile                  Display timing and memory usage information
      --no-plugins               Whether to disable plugins.
  -d, --working-dir=WORKING-DIR  If specified, use the given directory as working directory.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose           Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about           Short information about Composer
  archive         Create an archive of this composer package
  browse          Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  clear-cache     Clears composer's internal package cache.
  clearcache      Clears composer's internal package cache.
  config          Set config options
  create-project  Create new project from a package into given directory.
  depends         Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed
  diagnose        Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
  dump-autoload   Dumps the autoloader
  dumpautoload    Dumps the autoloader
  exec            Execute a vendored binary/script
  global          Allows running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER_HOME).
  help            Displays help for a command
  home            Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  info            Show information about packages
  init            Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
  install         Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  licenses        Show information about licenses of dependencies
  list            Lists commands
  outdated        Shows a list of installed packages that have updates available, including their latest version.
  prohibits       Shows which packages prevent the given package from being installed
  remove          Removes a package from the require or require-dev
  require         Adds required packages to your composer.json and installs them
  run-script      Run the scripts defined in composer.json.
  search          Search for packages
  self-update     Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  selfupdate      Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  show            Show information about packages
  status          Show a list of locally modified packages
  suggests        Show package suggestions
  update          Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  validate        Validates a composer.json and composer.lock
  why             Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed
  why-not         Shows which packages prevent the given package from being installed
```

```
############ /var/www#
```

## Problema 1 - No se arranca el *Composer* como *root*

Por una parte me aparece un mensaje diciéndome:

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Lo cual no entiendo porque estoy como *root* y he usado `sudo su`.

Dado que mi ingles es paupérrimo no me habia dado cuenta que era un simple consejo de que no debo ejecutar este archivo en modo ***root***.

## Problema 2 - No encuentra **composer.json**

A la hora de ejecutar cualquier comando *Composer* me devuelve los siguientes mensajes:

1. El mismo mensaje que el del **problema 1**:

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

2. Un mensaje que muestra que no encuentra el archivo **composer.json**:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www
>   To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

El archivo **composer.json** se encuentra en una carpeta distinta a la del **composer.phar**:

¿Cómo indico la ruta del archivo *JSON*?

## Problema 3 - ¿Está el archivo realmente instalado con *Composer*?

Aquí es donde más me pierdo la verdad, en teoría, por lo que he ido leyendo, los paquetes instalados aparecen en el archivo **composer.json**. Si eliminas las líneas donde se le hace referencia al paquete podrás borrar la carpeta y tener el paquete desinstalado.

Cuando yo accedo al **composer.json** aparece únicamente un paquete instalado, y no es el que quiero desinstalar.

Pero a pesar de eso, tengo mis dudas de si ese es el archivo correcto (por eso quería listar los paquetes instalados, para asegurarme), ya que en la carpeta donde debería ir el **composer.json** (por lo que he ido leyendo) es un ***vendor***.

Aquí dentro se encuentran dos carpetas:

1. **slim** (el framework que aparece en el archivo **composer.json**)
2. composer

Dentro de **slim** tenemos el archivo **composer.json** y aparece como que está instalado únicamente este paquete.

Dentro de **composer** tenemos varios *PHP* y un *JSON* llamado **installed.json** y dentro aparecen más líneas referenciando a **slim**.

<sub>Nota: He mirado en el paquete de *Reportico* para comprobar si ahí se encuentra otro archivo de **composer.json** pero no hay nada</sub>

Me gustaría tener una solución a estos problemas y por último que es realmente por lo que muestro estos problemas es... ¿Cómo debo desinstalar el paquete de *Reportico*?

---

## Decisión

He decidido eliminar la carpeta manualmente, aparentemente no ha generado ningún problema en la aplicación (lo he comprobado).

Puede que se instalara manualmente y que no la instalaran con el *Composer* (a pesar de lo que me dijeron).

Comment: Con "Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details" te indica que no debes usar composer como root, no que no lo esté ejecutando

Comment: @CésarGonzález Ok, problema uno solucionada. Ya esta editada la pregunta

Comment: has probado con `composer remove vendor/package` cambiando vendor por tu ruta

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez si he probado, pero me salta el mensaje de que no es capaz de leer el archivo de **composer.json**

Comment: El archivo `composer.json` realmente existe? El paquete fue instalado con composer anteriormente?

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara si, pero esta en una ruta distinta al archivo de `composer.path` y no lo encuentra y segun lo que me han dicho el paquete si que fue instalado con composer, pasaria algo si elimino directamente la carpeta?

Comment: ejecuta el comando composer en el mismo `path` donde esté el fichero composer.json, Para eliminar una dependencia (paquete) puedes usar `composer remove vendor/package` o eliminar tú mismo la línea del fichero composer.json y ejecutar `composer update`, esta última, te actualizará la versión de los paquetes existentes, así que cuidado.

Comment: He eliminado la carpeta de forma manual y no ha dado ningun problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aun que ya solucionaste el problema dejare la respuesta por si ha alguien le sirve.

Por lo general **Composer** puede ser instalado de forma local (para el poyecto concreto) o global, siendo esta última  lo más común. Cuando es instalado de forma local los archivos **composer.phar** y **composer.json** estarán ubicados en el mismo directorio en la raíz del proyecto por lo general y utilizará por convención la carpeta **/vendor/** en el mismo nivel para instalar las dependencias necesarias.

Para eleminar un paquete Composer provee el comando **remove**, debemos tener en cuenta que el comando buscará el archivo **composer.json** en el directorio actual es decir, en el que estemos ubicados, ya que este archivo contiene un objeto json con todas las dependencias instaladas por composer.

```
composer remove Nombre_del_paquete
```

Documentación Composer :

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove